# How Hide/Protect resource files against extractors?

Tags: c++, windows, security, embedded-resource

I have a executable file as resource of my main program, there's some way to Hide/protect my resource file against extractors like [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), [Resource Tuner](http://www.heaventools.com/rt-tour-resource-types.htm) between others?

Comment: There isn't any way to do this. Once you're handing out data you no longer control who's using it.

Comment: You can't. [Preventing reverse engineering with binary code and secret key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875519/preventing-reverse-engineering-with-binary-code-and-secret-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this. There is no way.

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875519/preventing-reverse-engineering-with-binary-code-and-secret-key) that could be useful.